# What is the difference between these two verbs “Servir” and “Desservir” ?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

I always notice this sentence when taking the train:

*Ce train desservira la gare ...*

I would like to know the difference between the "Servir" and "Desservir" verbs? and when to use each?

Comment: Did you search on the Internet for that? This usage of desservir is explained [here](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/desservir/24645?q=desservir#24527). Other usage [here](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/desservir/24646?q=desservir#24528) There is I think no situation in which you could use both and the situations in which you should use desservir are described in the definitions.

Comment: La question n'est absolument pas hors sujet. C'est un point difficile que l'OP a eu le mérite de soulever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Servir" = rendre un service/être au service de qq ou qqch.

"Desservir" =  "assurer un service" (***sens 1***)
(Source: CNTRL)

Il y a aussi le "desservir" qui signifie le contraire de servir.
(Usage du préfixe "dé-" pour signifier qu'on *défait* une action).

Exemples:
-Servir la table. Desservir la table. (***Sens 2***)
-ça me rend service. Cela me dessert (faire le contraire d'un service = nuire). (***Sens 3***)

**Il ne faut pas confondre les "desservir" formés à partir de "dé" dans le sens de défaire, et les "desservir" formés à partir du latin "deservire"** (« servir avec zèle, se consacrer à », ) Ce sont des homonymes en réalité.

Formé à partir de "deservire" = Sens 1.
Formé à partir de "dé + servir" (comme défaire)= Sens 2 et sens 3.

Tout le monde pense que c'est le même mot, car les deux mots sont absolument similaires, dans la prononciation et l'orthographe, mais ils n'ont ni le même sens, ni la même étymologie

---

Revenons au sens qui nous intéresse ici:

Un des sens de "desservir", est très précisément: "Assurer un service *en un lieu fixe*" (***Sens 4***)
Ils furent massacrés dans le palais qu'ils *desservaient*.

(Bien sûr, dans cette phrase on voit bien que le verbe desservir n'a pas le sens 2 ou 3 donné plus haut.).
Ce sens est archaïque, et pratiquement oublié.

Mais c'est de là, qu'on peut supposer que le sens suivant vient:

Assurer un service de communication (...) (ou de transport (***Sens 5***)
La route *desservait* uniquement les carrières de Bécourt.
Trois ascenseurs *desservent* les étages.

Entre un ascenseur qui "dessert" un étage, signifiant qu'il amène du route à cet endroit, et un train qui "dessert" une gare, signifiant la même chose, on saisit le lien.

De là, il y a aussi:
Accessible par des moyens de communication; équipé en moyens de communication.
 Ce quartier est mal desservi. = On a du mal à s'y rendre en voiture, train ou tout autre moyen de transport.

Le lien entre *servir* et *desservir* ici:

*Servir*: se mettre au service de...
*Desservir*: assurer un service de transport (pour se rendre à...)

Le fait que "desservir" était utilisé selon son sens archaïque (Sens 4) pour signifier qu'une personne assurait un service en un lieu, a fait passer petit à petit le sens vers "assurer un service (sous-entendu: de transport) en un lieu (=vers un lieu).
On ne l'utilise plus à présent pour des personnes (sauf rares expressions), mais pour des moyens de transports/ou des routes (Cette route dessert le village), avec le même sens: amener les gens en transport vers ce lieu.

On parle aussi d'une desserte.
= *voie de communication (ex: route), moyen de transport (ex: train) qui dessert un lieu.*

https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/desserte

Comment: Dire que *desservir* et *desservir* n'ont pas la même étymologie est à mon avis abusif. Ils viennent tous deux du préfixe *de-* et du verbe *servir*. Les sens distincts sont dus au fait que le préfixe *de-*, en latin comme en français, a plusieurs sens, voire parfois aucun...

Comment: Ce n'est pas abusif, c'est ce que les dictionnaires mentionnent. C'est-à-dire qu'ils ne font pas de glose sur leur définition, mais mentionnent le latin "deservire" (que vous pouvez vérifier dans le CNTRL par exemple).

Comment: Le "dé" privatif de "desservir", quand on dessert une table, est évident. Le "deservire" n'a pas ce "de" privatif, il veut dire l'inverse. Et c'est pour cela qu'on se retrouve avec un desservir avec le sens privatif (desservir la table, ou desservir dans le sens de nuire) et un desservir qui veut dire l'inverse: servir, qui s'appuie non pas sur le dé privatif, mais sur le desservire latin, qui veut dire le contraire d'un dé privatif.

Comment: ça explique l'apparente contradiction, mais si vous voulez contester l'étymologie latine et dire qu'il n'y a qu'une seule étymologie, alors vous allez à l'encontre de la lexicographie couramment admise (pourquoi pas, mais le deservire latin s'emploie pile-poil dans le sens 4, raison pour laquelle les dictionnaires la donne).

Comment: Et si vous contester l'étymologie "dé" dans le sens privatif de "desservir" (faire le contraire de servir, quand on dessert la table, on quand on fait le contraire de rendre un service), ça va à l'encontre du sens commun.

Comment: Je ne conteste pas le sens privatif de *de-* mais le verbe latin *servire* est à l'origine du verbe *deservire* et donc des deux verbes français "desservir". Il est donc abusif de dire que ces derniers n'ont pas la même étymologie puisqu'ils partagent le même radical et un même préfixe polysémique. Qu'ils n'aient pas le même sens est une évidence, mais rien n'interdit à deux mots ayant la même étymologie d'avoir des sens différents, voire opposés. Par exemple on peut comparer en français et en anglais journée et *journey*, éventuellement et *eventually* ou patron et *patron*.

Comment: C'est votre opinion à vous, encore une fois, ce n'est pas celle des dictionnaires. (Il faut donc leur expliquer qu'ils se trompent) Le "deservire" latin est le seul à pouvoir expliquer le sens ancien: "être de service dans une maison ou une même place", qui vous a échappé, car il est archaïque (mais on ne peut pas le balayer de la main comme s'il n'avait jamais existé).

Comment: De plus, le deservire latin a, comme je l'ai déjà dit, exactement ce sens-là. Utiliser le dé-servir pour expliquer ce sens conduit à un échec. Le mot latin "deservire" ne s'est pas perdu, puisque son sens a survécu dans cet usage archaïque.

Comment: Vous n'êtes pas latinisant. Le "dé" n'a pas ce sens en latin. dēservĭō = servir avec zèle. Nulle part il n'y a un sens privatif "dé".

Comment: C'est étrange de penser que le "de" latin doit avoir un sens privatif parce que c'est le cas en français.

Comment: Il y a bien une racine commune avec "servire" par contre, bien sûr. Mais l'un vient directement de "servire" (servir) avec un dé- ajouté en français (privatif), sur lequel nous sommes d'accord. Et l'autre vient directement du latin "deservire". Pas moi que le dit, c'est le CNRTL citation:  Du lat. deservire « servir avec zèle, se consacrer à »,

Comment: L'erreur est de penser que le latin "deservire" signifie "desservir"!

Comment: " Par exemple on peut comparer en français et en anglais journée et journey, éventuellement et eventually ou patron et patron". Pour "patron", c'est facilement explicable par le latin. Et pour "journée" et "journey", c'est également enfantin à expliquer. Le passage d'un mot du français en anglais n'a de toute façon rien à voir avec les différents sens contradictoires d'un même mot en français. Notez que le sens "deservire" est le premier historiquement, pas l'inverse.

Comment: Bon, c'est comme vous voulez. Je ne dis pas que le CNTRL ne peut pas se tromper, même si en général, c'est une référence, c'est tout de même possible. Mais dire que c'est "abusif", étant donné que ce n'est pas moi qui ai inventé tout ceci, est aussi "abusif".

Comment: Dites que vous n'êtes pas d'accord avec le CNTRL, c'est votre droit (et c'est même sain de n'être pas d'accord, ça stimule le débat), mais ça n'a rien d'abusif, car ce n'est pas dit en l'air sans rien en guise d'arguments derrière. Il faudrait mettre sérieusement le nez dans les premières occurrences de ce mot, l'étymologie deservire semble être la seule qui existe en ancien français, et le desservir est beaucoup plus récent.

Comment: 1. Abusif ne veut pas dire faux mais exagéré, excessif. 2. Le préfixe *de-* pouvait déjà avoir un sens privatif en latin. J'ai donné deux exemples dans ma réponse. Il y en a d'autres comme *mens* / *demens*, *formare* / *deformare*. Le préfixe *dé-* français vient directement du latin. 3. L'étymologie d'un mot ne débute pas à sa première apparition, elle consiste à rechercher à partir de quel(s) mot(s) plus anciens est construit un mot donné. Par exemple, l'étymologie de cinéma(tographe) remonte bien au grec ancien *κίνημα* et *γράφω* même s'il s'agit d'un néologisme du XIXᵉ siècle.

Answer (score 4):

«Servir» is a verb having many meanings, but never related to train stops. Usually used to refer to :

- "serve [someone/something]" as being useful for : je sers d'indic à la police, je sers mon pays.
- "distributing something" (such as food) : j'ai servi le repas

"Desservir" is used specifically to describe where a bus / train will make intermediate stops prior to the final destination : "le train desservira les gares de xxx, yyy et son terminus zzz"

With this you should not be confused anymore. Please tell me if it's not clear enough.

Comment: "Desservir" has other usages but you're right that "Servir" can not be used in the context of OP's question.

Comment: Your answer is interesting, but as you worded it, it contains a self-contradiction. " but never related to train stops" "is used specifically to describe where a bus / train will make intermediate stops "

Comment: Dans le "dessert", ça ne veut absolument pas dire que c'est un distribution de nourriture, c'est plutôt un plagt qu'on présent quand on a fini le service. Le sens ancien donné dans les dictionnaires est "dernier service du repas".

Comment: @Quidam Nicholas n'a jamais écrit que le dessert était une distribution de quoi que ce soit. La question concernait les verbes servir et desservir.

Comment: ""distributing something" (such as food) : j'ai servi le dessert"

Comment: Ah oui, peut-être qu'il voulait illustrer "servir", mais dans ce cas, ça crée la confusion avec "dessert", qui a le sens opposé.

Comment: J'ai modifié le texte pour changer le mot dessert par un autre afin de lever la confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some sentences using various words etymologically related to the Latin *servus* (slave) :

> *Aucun train ne **dessert** cette gare qui ne **sert** donc à rien.*
>
> *Le **serveur** nous a rendu **service** en nous **servant** rapidement le **dessert**. Il a ensuite **desservi** la table sur une **desserte***.
>
> *Ce **serveur** web est trop souvent hors-**service**, ça **dessert** nos intérêts et ceux de nos clients.*

The Latin verb *servire* (fr:*servir*) kept most of its meanings. It is present in English too as "to serve".

In Latin, *servire* was used to coin the verb *deservire* which has essentially the same meaning, the prefix *de-* playing no significant semantic role here.

We inherited/use a few words also unaffected by the presence of this prefix like:

> *nommé* and ***dé**nommé*
>
> *compter* and ***dé**compter*
>
> *limiter* and ***dé**limiter*

and thus, *servir* and ***de**sservir* as in *ce train dessert la gare de Montélimar*.

This *desservir* meant *mériter* in early French and was adopted with this meaning in English as *to deserve*.

On the other hand, the very same prefix *de-* (also *dis-*) could also mean "opposite of" like in *faire et **dé**faire* (do and undo).

For example the Latin had *florere* (*fleurir*) and *deflorare* (*déflorer*) or *gradare* (*donner un grade/graduer*) and *degradare* (*dégrader*).

The verb *desservir* is also present on this side and in that case means the opposite of *servir*.

It's a little far fetched but we might then write:

> *Ne pas desservir la gare, c'est la desservir.* (Not serving the station is against its interests).

Comment: Aujourd'hui j'ai vu **des cerfs**.

ok je sors...

Comment: @Steph ou des **serfs**...

Comment: Il faudrait expliquer. Là, ce sont des exemples.

Comment: @Quidam Une autre réponse le faisait déjà bien.

Comment: Alors pourquoi ne pas rajouter en commentaire, ou faire une réponse complète? Dans cet exemple, peut-être que ça aide l'utilisateur, je ne peux pas juger à sa place, mais moi ça me ferait l'effet inverse, car tous les sens sont mélangés (Quand j'apprends une langue, le seul fait de lire les exemples d'usages, sans avoir la moindre explication à côté, souvent ça me perturbe encore plus). En tout cas, si je me trompe et que cette réponse lui est utile, elle ne le sera que plus en assortissant les exemples d'explications. ça ne peut pas nuire.

Comment: @Quidam Si je n'ai pas mis d'explication ou de commentaires à mes exemples d'utilisation de mots de la même famille que servir et desservir, c'est simplement parce que l'OP n'a fait aucun effort de recherche. Ma réponse est là pour l'inciter à ouvrir un dictionnaire. C'est plus positif que demander une fermeture de la question, ce que j'ai hésité à faire.

Comment: J'ai mis le nez dans le dictionnaire, et quand on voit tous les différents sens de ce mot, je comprends qu'il y a une confusion. Y compris dans celle de ceux dont c'est la language maternelle.

Comment: Il aurait été bien que l'auteur cite les définitions trouvées dans le dictionnaire dans son message, mais à moins d'avoir ces sens bien particuliers expliqués par une personne francophone, ça n'aurait probablement pas changé grand chose, ce n'est pas comme si les sens de ce mot étaient évident (contrairement à ce que quelqu'un d'autre dit plus haut), tout ce que vous voulez qu'il aurait été tout de même confus. (aussi étant donné que beaucoup de francophones le sont aussi).

Comment: Les dictionnaires ne donnent pas forcément une explication permettant de détacher ce qui est commun dans les définitions, ils ne font que compiler les sens. Je suis en cours de rédaction d'un dictionnaire qui ne fait pas que compiler (déjà trouvé l'éditeur), mais compare les sens, donc j'en sais quelque chose.

Comment: @Quidam Bon, j'ai suivi tes conseils et étoffé ma réponse.

Comment: Je dé-downvote!

Comment: Voilà, le "dé" est bien dans le sens privatif que j'ai donné. Et l'autre étymologie du latin "deservire" existe aussi bel et bien (ou les dictionnaires racontent n'importe quoi). Donc, ce n'est absolument pas abusif de donner 2 étymologies.